# Does California Penal Code 1214.1 disallow the requirement to pay bail before Trial by Written Declaration?

Tags: california, trial

California Penal Code 1214.1(b2) states:

> Payment of a civil assessment shall not be required to schedule a
>   court hearing on a pending underlying charge.

However, California Traffic Courts require pre-payment of bail before allowing a Trial by Written Declaration.

Is this allowed by the Penal Code?

Comment: If the bail was required before any hearing, it would be disallowed. But you only refer to one type of hearing - if others do not require bail, you can have them scheduled before any payment occurs, unless other unreasonableness also precludes it. Need a legal reference to confirm this as an answer.

Comment: So they can require it for a trial by written declaration as long as there is *some* sort of trial that I can arrange that doesn't require it, even if I am not local and the trial by written declaration is the only reasonable option?

Comment: And what legal reference do you need supplied?  I'll happily find what I can.

Comment: Something either as precedent or in the law itself, to say "as long as other options exist" would be enough.

Comment: @DavidLjungMadison: In general, my understanding is bail would not be considered a civil assessment, as the latter is a fee. Bail is generally a bond, returned to the payer upon completion of their obligations; in this case paying any judgement ordered by the court.